# Which way to say "What time is it"?

Tags: translation

I want to say "what time is it" so I did some research. But there are two ways to say it. The first way is

> che ora è?

and the second one is

> che ore sono?

I'm not sure if the second one makes sense.

Comment: Both are correct, but of course you need the question mark at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both corrects. Here the reasons:

http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/C/che-ora-e-che-ore-sono.shtml

Comment: se la domanda è posta in inglese il link a un testo in lingua Italia potrebbe non essere d'aiuto, salvo che non si metta la traduzione.